# How to use styles on content that has been generated by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the .box div(s) in the `:hover` selector, I can only get this to work when I put an `!important` flag next to the CSS rule. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style id="styles" type="text/css">
    .box:hover {
        background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        for (var i=0;i<500;i++) {
            document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='box' style='display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;float:left;'></div>";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read up on CSS specificity. !important is a blunt tool. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: This is one of the reasons to *not* use inline CSS. Move the rest of the CSS to the style block and you won't have the same problem.

Comment: @JakeKing this makes sense, but what if I wanted to use javascript to apply dynamic styles for each element in the loop e.g. width. & keep the ability to use the hover selector

Comment: @Halpo In such a case, define only the element-specific item in the style and move the rest to the stylesheet. The "lock" only affects the properties you define!

Comment: @Halpo In most cases, there is a way to organize your classes to keep most styles off of your elements directly, but in some cases, `!important` is necessary. Yes, it's a hack that should be avoided, but using it here and there when there is no other way is not terrible.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is the information I needed, thanks!

Comment: @JakeKing thanks for clearing this up; it makes much more sense to me now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styles defined in the `style="..."` attribute have higher specificity than anything defined in stylesheets.

You should instead define your styles like this:

```
<style>
    .box {
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        display:inline-block; /* better than float:left for your usage */
    }
    .box:hover {background-color:blue}
</style>
```

You should also never use `+=` with `.innerHTML`.

```
for( var i=0; i<500; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).className = "box";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the styles in inline.. Try like below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style id="styles" type="text/css">
    .box{
       display:block;
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
       background-color:red;
       float:left;
     }
    .box:hover {
       background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>HELLO!</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    for (var i=0;i<500;i++) {
      document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='box'></div>";
    }
    var content = document.getElementById('styles').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('styles').innerHTML = content;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** when you apply a style from script it can be only overwritten by using !important.